# issue '381' with ranges VBA

Tags: vba, excel, range

I have following code for filling a ListBox

```
Function fillData()

    Dim vList As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets(BD)

    With ws
        If (IsEmpty(.Range("D2").Value) = False) Then

            Dim lastCell As String: lastCell = "D" & .Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row
            vList = ws.Range("D2:" & lastCell).Value


            Me.ListBox1.List = vList
        End If

        Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1

    End With

    Set vList = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Function
```

Everything works good so far...

[image]

but when I left just one row with data this error appears:

[image]

I even printed my range with this:

```
MsgBox "the range is D2:" & celdaFin
```

this is what I got

[image]

and then the error message appears, how to do this work also with one cell??

---

**EDIT:** Solution thanks to @Jason and @tospig

```
Function fillData()

    Dim vList As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets(BD)

    Me.ListBox1.Clear

    With ws
        If (IsEmpty(.Range("D2").Value) = False) Then

            vList = ws.Range("D2:D" & .Range("D65536").End(xlUp).Row).Value

            If IsArray(vList) Then
                Me.ListBox1.List = vList
            Else
                Me.ListBox1.AddItem (vList)
            End If


        End If

        Me.ListBox1.ListIndex = -1

    End With

    Set vList = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the same reasons as @Jason_Walker pointed out, if your `variant` is an array you can check for it using `IsArray`. If not, you can add it as a single item

```
If IsArray(vList) Then
    Me.ListBox1.List = vList
Else
    Me.ListBox1.AddItem = vList
End if
```

**Update**

For completeness, @Jason_Walker 's reasons:

*"Any time the variant is populated by a range with more than one value, it automatically creates a 2-D array.
The 2-D array should populate the listbox with no issues.
The array is not a 2-D array if there is only one value in the range"*

Comment: thanks you both, with @Jason coment and your solution I could make it work, I'll update the code with the solution implemented

Comment: Excellent Choice by @tospig with the IsArray Function

Answer (score 2):

Any time the variant is populated by a range with more than one value, it automatically creates a 2-D array.

The 2-D array should populate the listbox with no issues.

The array is not a 2-D array if there is only one value in the range so you may have to redim the variant manually

You may have to test the array if it is only one value

If it is only one value then

```
Redim vList(1 to 1, 1 to 1)
vList(1,1) = ws.Range("D2:" & lastCell).Value
```

The listbox should be able to take the variant at this point